# How to check if layer is time enabled?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, flex

I want to be able to loop through the layers in my map, and return the names of layers that  are time-enabled.

I understand that I will need to check [TimeInfo](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/apiref/com/esri/ags/layers/supportClasses/TimeInfo.html) and this could be enabled on a dynamic, feature or Image service within the map.

I am looking for the **tidiest** way of doing this, in its own function that can be called and a name of a layer returned.  I have been messing about with some If statements within a 'for each' loop, but I keep struggling and making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Any advice/pointers/snippets on how to code this up in Flex would be appreciated.

Comment: I would be concerned about that assumption (each map has only one time-enabled layer) unless you have very strict control over the map contents.

Comment: Bonus points for catching multiple layers, but yes - a limitation of my tool will be that it will only assume one layer is time enabled from the map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not your full answer, but a starting point:

```
var timeInfo:TimeInfo;

if (layer is ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer)
{
    timeInfo = (layer as ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer).timeInfo;
}
else if (layer is ArcGISImageServiceLayer)
{
    timeInfo = (layer as ArcGISImageServiceLayer).timeInfo;
}
else if (layer is FeatureLayer)
{
    var feaLayer:FeatureLayer = layer as FeatureLayer;
    if (feaLayer.layerDetails)
    {
        timeInfo = feaLayer.layerDetails.timeInfo;
    }
}
```

// straight from the TimeWidget of the [ArcGIS Viewer for Flex](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/)

Comment: Hi Bjorn - I have been basing a lot of my code on the time widget.  I will see if I can tweak this section code to put it into a ForEach loop to check each layer.